# Angular Modal with Dynamic Content that has Custom Directives

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to display a dynamic form which contains custom directives as a modal.  I have tried to use ng-bind-html but the html content that has custom directive shows up empty and throws error "The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html:"

Here is the running [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjbYLXAG6JYcOxOzlz7G?p=preview).  Please advise.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.textvalue = "";
  $scope.cbvalue = "";

});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;

  $scope.textvalue;
  $scope.ddvalue;

  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('customTextinput', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
      label: "=",
      fieldvalue: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "customti.html",
    controller: function($scope, $log){

    }
  }
})
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('customDropdown', function(){
    return {
      restrict: "EA",
      scope: {
        label: "="
      },
      templateUrl: "customcb.html",
      controller: function($scope, $modal, $sce){
        $scope.showModal = function(){
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation:true,
            templateUrl: 'modaldemo.html',
            backdrop: 'static',
            controller: function($scope, $log, $modalInstance){
              $scope.myContent = '<custom-textinput label="\'Text Input\'" ng-model="textvalue"';
                //$scope.myContent = "<p>Hello World</p>";
                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close('');
                }
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                }
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need module called ngSanitize take a look on angular docs here

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

After installing this .You can use $sce service like this

```
var cleanHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
```

It will solve sanitizer errors.Also do not forget to inject it into direcitve.

Comment: Sorry tried that.  It does not work.  the code has ngsanitize.